# Proof Writing: Given 2 two dimensional manifolds $\emptyset \neq N \subseteq M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, $N$ is compact, $M$ is pconnected: $N = M$

Tags: proof-writing, manifolds

**Statement:** Given 2 two-dimensional manifolds $\emptyset \neq N \subseteq M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 $, if $N$ is compact and $M$ is path-connected, then $N = M$.

*Proof:*
We know that there is at least one point $p\in N$ and we assume that there exists another point $q \notin N, q \in M$. From path-connectivity we get that there exists a path $\gamma(t) : [0,1] \rightarrow M$, such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$.

Label $t_0$ that maximum $t \in [0,1]$ such that $\gamma(t) \in N$. This exists an is well defined because $N$ is compact. We label $\gamma(t_0) = x_0$.

*Claim:* $T_{x_0}M = T_{x_0}N$. From $N \subseteq M$ we get $T_{x_0}N \subseteq T_{x_0}M$. This, coupled with the fact that they are both 2-dimensional linear spaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and therefore they have to be equal.

**
I now want to say that because of this, I can "continue going along with the path" and get closer to $q$ while staying on $N$, and therefore $t_0$ isn't maximal, a contradiction.

I'm not really sure how to formally express this, I know that intuitively, the the tangent space is an "up close" look at the manifold and that I can go along the tangent space and stay on the manifold, but I'm not sure how to formally say this.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your proof so far is good, but there is no need to pass to the tangent space.

*Sketch:* The point $x_0$ has an open neighborhood $U\subseteq N$ homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there is an induced open ball $B\subseteq[0,1]$ at $t_0\in B\subseteq[0,1]$ such that the path $\gamma(B)\subseteq U$.  This then implies that $t_0=1$ lest we contradict the definition of $t_0$.

**NB**: The above sketch of a proof assumes that $N$ is a manifold without boundary.  If $N$ has boundary, then the statement is false (e.g. look at a closed disk living in the sphere).

Comment: Yes, I can't assume that $N$ is without a boundary. I do know that $N$ is two-dimensional, and so I think I had to use the tangent space...

Comment: @JohnB: If $N$ has boundary, then the statement you have given can be false (I provided a counterexample in my answer).  Also, you don't know that the tangent spaces to points in $N$ are defined unless these are smooth embeddings, and then boundary is sort of an annoying problem.